# Why is the empty set considered a family of sets?

Tags: set-theory

As far as I understand, a set is considered to be a family of sets if and only if it is the case that the elements of this set are sets themselves. Since the empty set does not contain any elements by definition, should it not be the case that the empty set is not a family of sets? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Every element of the empty set is a set. Look up the term "vacuously true".

Comment: Equally true is that every element of the empty set is _not_ a set. Lookup the previous comment.

Comment: The only way for " every element in a set, is a set" to be false is if there is an element in the set, which is not a set. i.e. A counterexample. There are no such for the empty set. Note: Rather than family of sets, it is common terminology to call such a set a hereditary set.

Answer (score 2):

The rationale presumably comes from a vacuous argument: can you find an element $x$ of $\emptyset$ such that $x$ is not a set?

This would require that $x \in \emptyset$ to begin with, so it can't hold.

You may think of this instead, perhaps, as "all zero of the elements of the empty set are sets" -- it's not the "zero" that matters, but the "all".

Answer (score 2):

There's an old joke that goes like this: In a butcher's shop, a customer asks the butcher what the price of brisket is. The butcher says the price is $\$1.20$ per pound. (This is a *very* old joke!)

"But at Mr. Fink's shop across the street, his price is $\$1.10$."

"Well, why don't you go buy your brisket from Mr. Fink?"

"He's all out of brisket."

"If I were out of brisket, my price could be $\$1.10$ too."

---

In mathematical logic, if your set is "all out of" elements -- that is, if it's the empty set, which has no elements -- then you can declare that the elements of your set are anything you like, just as a butcher who has no brisket to sell can afford to set its price at anything he likes.

But that's not a complete answer to the question, in my opinion, because we could have defined a *family of sets* to be a *non-empty* set whose elements are sets themselves.
So why don't we do that?

I think the reason is that there are times when mathematicians would like to be able to take intersections or set differences of families of sets and be able to call the result also a family of sets. And in some of those cases, the intersection of set difference might be empty. So if the empty set were not a family of sets, there would be times when someone either would have to call the intersection or set difference of families of sets something other than a family of sets, or would have to somehow ensure that the intersection or set difference was never empty, and this would make some definitions and proofs more complicated.

On the other hand, if (for some reason) someone needs a family of sets not to be empty, they can say "non-empty family of sets." And if we have a collection of families of sets, there is nothing that says that the empty set has to be an element of that particular collection.

So the usual definition of a family of sets avoids inconveniences and creates very little inconvenience itself, compared to a definition that requires the family to be non-empty. And mathematicians like definitions that are convenient to use.

Comment: The math.se interface is missing the ability for me to give you a rim shot. So here's the closest I can get >ba-dum, tish<.